# GameObject doesn't contain a definition for AddForce

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was using this code to make bullets shoot like a shotgun.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{
    var b = Instantiate(bullet, Firepoint.position, Firepoint.rotation)
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            b.AddForce(Firepoint.right * bulletFireVel + new Vector3(0f, -90f, 0f));
            break;
        case 1:
            b.AddForce(Firepoint.right * bulletFireVel + new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f));
            break;
        case 2:
            b.AddForce(Firepoint.right * bulletFireVel + new Vector3(0f, 90f, 0f));
            break;
    }
}
```

but this gave me this error

> Assets\Shooting.cs(49,23): error CS1061: 'GameObject' does not contain
> a definition for 'AddForce' and no accessible extension method
> 'AddForce' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject' could be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

sorry for my bad english.
how can I solve this?

Comment: Have you attached a `Rigidbody` to your gameObject? `AddForce`  is the method of class [Rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html). So you might have to use `b.GetComponent < Rigidbody > ().AddForce ( someValue );`

Comment: The error message sounds pretty self-explanatory ... simply make sure that the type of `bullet` is a `Rigidbody`. `Instantiate` returns the se type of the original prefab, this way you don't need `GetComponent`

Answer (score 0):

AddForce is a method that has be used on a RigidBody and not just a GameObject. Here's what to do:

1. Make sure your bullets have a RigidBody Component.
2. Try:

`b.GetComponent<RigidBody>().AddForce();`

You may need to tinker with the Vector3 you're putting in (I always have to tinker with it) but this should get the Rigid Body attached to your bullet and send it on its way.

But check out the [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) on AddForce as well.